# Analytical expression of Pearson's correlation

Tags: probability-distributions

I do not understand the notation of Spearman's correlation in the article of
B Schweizer, EF Wolff - The annals of statistics, 1981 - JSTOR
given by
$\rho = \frac{1}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}\int_{R^2}( F_{X,Y}(x,y) - F_X(x)F_Y(y)) dx dy$

Whn I use analytical formula of the correlation
$\rho = E(XY) - E(X) E(Y)$
gives
$\rho = \int_{R^2}( f_{X,Y}(x,y) - f_X(x) f_Y(y) )dx dy$

Should I developp the above two expresions to find an equivalence or is there any probability property to apply to get directly the result?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The integral in your second paragraph is equal to $0$, which is probably not what you meant to write.  Maybe the formula that puzzles you is related to the result described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_case_2 .

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the article that is pretty useful,

I may believe that my second integral is equal to 0 only in the case of independance $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are independant random variables,
Additional example is the independant copula is given by $C(u,v)=uv$ were according to Sklar theorem $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=C(u,v)$, the joint distribution function accepts one and one copula only

Comment: As to your second integral: $\int_{R^2}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy=1$ and $\int_Rf_X(x)dx=1$ and $\int_Rf_Y(y)dy=1$, so the whole thing equals $1-1\times1=0$.

Comment: True I meant to write $\int_{R^2}[xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)-xf_X(x)yf_Y(y)]dxdy$